# Keep track of item in recylerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am making a chat application in which when the user hits send button , the message is added to the recycler view and at the same time sent to the server.How can i keep track of the message item in recycler view so that if the message is not successfully sent to the server (due to network problem ),i can show a resend option next to that message.

following is the flow

```
 sendMessageToServer(message);
 messageItems.add(message);
 notifyItemRangeInserted
```

Comment: You can use something similar to `Map<String MessageID, Boolean ServerCheck>`, once delivered change the boolean value in the `Map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution -but not the most correct one- would be as the following:

1. add a boolean attribute `isSuccessful` to the message class.
2. when you send the message and the get the response back from the server change the corresponding message. and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the Adapter.

and I recommend this [take](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BlkJzgjzL0c) where they build [this open source messing app](https://github.com/yigit/dev-summit-architecture-demo) to get a better understanding how to design you Application Architecture, as my solution is not the best but I guess is the easiest.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply,this would work in my case,I have one more ques ,suppose i want to delete that message from the recyclerview then how could i do it.I need the position of that item in recylerview,How do i get it

Comment: you can attach onClickListenr to the row in on bindView and there you can get the position and delete the message from your data set and then call notifyDataSetChanged